# More efficient way to loop through tuple and obtain list of lists of transitions from high to low

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, tuples

I have a tuple of input integer values, and a value of *high*. I want to loop through and pull out pairs of the first instance of a value in the tuple that is >= *high*, and then first value that is < *high*. An example might help:

Keep only the first high or first low of each repeating high or low

For instance, if max == 100, and the input is (**102**, 109, 120, **80**, 40, 30, **200**, **90**)

output should be [[102, 80], [200, 90]]

```
items = (102, 109, 120, 80, 40, 30, 200, 90)
high = 100
started = False  # Used to ensure we start with high values first
currently_on_highs = True
first_val_high = True
first_val_low = True
transitions = []
inner_transition = []

for item in items:
    if item >= high:
        started = True
        currently_on_highs = True
        if first_val_high:
            first_val_high = False
            first_val_low = True
            inner_transition.append(item)
    else:
        if started:
            currently_on_highs = False
            if first_val_low:
                first_val_high = True
                first_val_low = False
                inner_transition.append(item)
                transitions.append(inner_transition)
                inner_transition = []

print(transitions)
```

---

Here's a much better result after the suggestion from @michael-butscher

```
items = (102, 109, 120, 80, 40, 30, 200, 90)
high = 100
in_high = False
transitions = []
inner_transition = []

for item in items:
    if item >= high and not in_high:
        in_high = True
        inner_transition.append(item)
    elif item < high and in_high:
        in_high = False
        inner_transition.append(item)
        transitions.append(inner_transition)
        inner_transition = []

print(transitions)
```

Comment: You only need one boolean variable (e.g. `in_high`). If you find a high value **and** `in_high` is False, start new inner transition with the value, set `in_high` True. Else if a value is low and `in_high` is True, close inner transition and change`in_high`. Other possible conditions aren't of interest.

Comment: More efficient in what dimension? Lines of code? CPU time? Memory? You could probably subtract 100 from all values and just act on sign changes.

Comment: Thanks, @michael-butscher

Comment: Thanks, @schlenk You gave me something good to mull over.

Comment: @djangomachine My answer is still shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with zip by offsetting the elements by one entry to compare each of them with their predecessor:

```
items  = (102, 109, 120, 80, 40, 30, 200, 90)
high   = 100
bounds = [ num for prev,num in zip((high-1,)+items,items) if (num<high)^(prev<high) ] 
result = list(zip(bounds[::2],bounds[1::2]))
print(result) # [(102, 80), (200, 90)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
items = (102, 109, 120, 80, 40, 30, 200, 90)
high = 100

ret = []
findh = True
for i in items:
    if findh and i >= high:
        findh = False
        ret.append([i])
    elif not findh and i < high:
        findh = True
        ret[-1].append(i)

print(ret)
```

---

Explanation:

- `ret = []` what we will add the pairs to
- `findh = True` whether or not we should look for a higher value
- `if findh and i >= high:` if we are looking higher and it is higer

  - `findh = False` look lower in future
  - `ret.append([i])` add another list to our master list, with just this value in
- `elif not findh and i < high:` if we are looking lower and it is lower

  - `findh = True` look higher in future
  - `ret[-1].append(i)` add this value to the last list in the master list

Answer (score 0):

A first step could be creating a list of all "switch" values:

```
items = (102, 109, 120, 80, 40, 30, 200, 90)
high = 100

res = []
last = high-1
for x in items:
    if last < high <= x or x <= high < last: 
        res.append(x) 
    last = x
```

then you can build the pairs:

```
res = [(res[i], res[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(res), 2)]
```